# How to make discord bot timed mute automatic for 5 mins?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, mute

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class AntiCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
      
        if message.author.id == 1234567891234567:
            mention = f'<@!1234567891234567>'
            if message.content == mention:
                await message.channel.send("grow up")
                user = message.author
                print(str(user))
                print(str(message.content))
                muted_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Muted")
                await user.add_roles(muted_role)

            else:
                return 

            await self.client.process_commands(message)
      
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(AntiCog(client))
```

This's a working code for muting a person if they ping another person, however, I would like to make it a timed mute for 5 min. All of the resources I found were on_command timed mute, however, this's an auto one, how can I do so. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would have to do is add asyncio.sleep, and then remove the role, so:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

class AntiCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
      
        if message.author.id == 1234567891234567:
            mention = f'<@!1234567891234567>'
            if message.content == mention:
                await message.channel.send("grow up")
                user = message.author
                print(str(user))
                print(str(message.content))
                muted_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Muted")
                await user.add_roles(muted_role)
                await asyncio.sleep(300) # you can change the time here
                await user.remove_roles(muted_role)

            else:
                return 

            await self.client.process_commands(message)
      
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(AntiCog(client))
```

Be sure to import asyncio!

Comment: never thought i'd be this simple with asyncio, thanks you so much for introducing this module to me xd